# Image rotation and editing stopped working in Wordpress after upgrading Ubuntu from 16.04 to 18.04

Tags: php, media, linux

I'm seeing this error in Wordpress Media editor:

> "Image rotation is not supported by your web host."

I checked on my server and I have php7-gd:

```
php -i | grep -i gd
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini,
gd
GD Support => enabled
GD headers Version => 2.2.5
GD library Version => 2.2.5
gd.jpeg_ignore_warning => 1 => 1
```

Does anyone know what could be a problem here?

Comment: Can you run `php -r "echo function_exists('imagerotate') ? 'exists' : 'does not exist';"` via command line?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I ran the command, but it doesn't return anything. What does this mean? lucas@vm14:~$ php -r "echo function_exists('imagerotate') ? 'exists' : 'does not exist';"
existslucas@vm14:~$

Comment: GD uses the function `imagerotate` for rotating images. This command should return `exists` if the function exists, and `does not exist` if not. Because of memory problems this function isn't available on all operating systems. My guess is that your setup is affected by this problem, and rotating images is not possible with GD. You can try to use Imagick instead.

Answer (score 1):

GD uses the function `imagerotate`. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5407035/7409991) on stackoverflow the function isn't included on some OS'es because of a memory leak. This problem is also mentioned as comment in the [WordPress code](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/class-wp-image-editor-gd.php#L31):

> On some setups GD library does not provide imagerotate() - Ticket #11536

The ticket number belongs to the WordPress Ticket [#11536](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/11536).

As a solution you can try to use the workaround mentioned in the stackoverflow answer or you can install php-imagick as an alternative to gd, which is also supported by WordPress.